# Disable Next button when fields aren't correctly filled out (block next step) - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to disable "Next" button when fields aren't correctly filled out? I would like block this step.
I using ***passwordRules[]*** and ***emailRules[]***.

***:disabled=""*** working for buttons in specific steps, but I don't know how to use it for inputs rules.

Could someone please help me solve this problem?

**Demo code:** https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/JjbZLKz

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      width="100%"
      max-width="400"
    >
      <v-card-title class="title font-weight-regular justify-space-between">
        <span>{{ currentTitle }}</span>
        <v-avatar
          color="primary lighten-2"
          class="subheading white--text"
          size="24"
          v-text="step"
        ></v-avatar>
      </v-card-title>
  
      <v-window v-model="step">
        <v-window-item :value="1">
          <v-card-text>
            <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            :counter="50"
            label="Email"
            minlength="5"
            maxlength="50"
            required
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-window-item>
  
        <v-window-item :value="2">
          <v-card-text>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="password"
              :rules="passwordRules"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="confirmPassword"
              :rules="passwordRules"
              label="Confirm Password"
              type="password"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-window-item>
  
        <v-window-item :value="3">
          <div class="pa-4 text-center">
            <v-img
              class="mb-4"
              contain
              height="128"
              src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/v.svg"
            ></v-img>
            <h3 class="title font-weight-light mb-2">
              Welcome to Vuetify
            </h3>
            <span class="caption grey--text">Thanks for signing up!</span>
          </div>
        </v-window-item>
      </v-window>
  
      <v-divider></v-divider>
  
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn
          :disabled="step === 1"
          text
          @click="step--"
        >
          Back
        </v-btn>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn
          :disabled="step === 3"
          color="primary"
          depressed
          @click="step++"
        >
          Next
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    step: 1,
    email: '',
    emailRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Email is required',
      v => v.length >= 5 || 'The e-mail address must contain at least 5 characters',
      v => v.length <= 50 || 'The e-mail address cannot be longer than 50 characters',
      v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Please enter a valid email address',
    ],
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    passwordRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Password is required',
      v => v.length >= 8 || 'Password must contain at least 8 characters',
      v => v.length <= 50 || 'Password address cannot be longer than 50 characters',
    ],
  }),

  computed: {
    currentTitle () {
      switch (this.step) {
        case 1: return 'Sign-up'
        case 2: return 'Create a password'
        default: return 'Account created'
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Check the docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#usage in the example they are using the `v-form` component  which can be bound with v-model to the variable where you want to store the validity of the whole form for example : `<v-form v-model="valid">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this helps

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/zYoyKYP)

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
<v-card class="mx-auto" width="100%"  max-width="400">
  <v-card-title class="title font-weight-regular justify-space-between">
    <span>{{ currentTitle }}</span>
    <v-avatar color="primary lighten-2"  class="subheading white--text" size="24"
      v-text="step"
    ></v-avatar>
  </v-card-title>

  <v-window v-model="step">
    <v-window-item :value="1">
      <v-form v-model="isFormValid">
      <v-card-text>
        <v-text-field  v-model="email" :rules="emailRules" :counter="50"
            label="Email" minlength="5"  maxlength="50"  required
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card-text>
      </v-form>
    </v-window-item>

    <v-window-item :value="2">
      <v-form v-model="isFormValid">
      <v-card-text>
        <v-text-field v-model="password" :rules="passwordRules" label="Password"
          type="password"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="confirmPassword" :rules="passwordRules"
          label="Confirm Password" type="password"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card-text>
      </v-form>
    </v-window-item>

    <v-window-item :value="3">
      <div class="pa-4 text-center">
        <v-img  class="mb-4"  contain  height="128"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/v.svg"
        ></v-img>
        <h3 class="title font-weight-light mb-2">Welcome to Vuetify</h3>
        <span class="caption grey--text">Thanks for signing up!</span>
      </div>
    </v-window-item>
  </v-window>

  <v-divider></v-divider>

  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn :disabled="!isFormValid ||step === 1" text @click="step--">
      Back
    </v-btn>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn :disabled=" !isFormValid || step === 3" color="primary" depressed @click="step++">
      Next
    </v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
  </v-app>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
data: () => ({
step: 1,isFormValid: false,
email: '',
emailRules: [
  v => !!v || 'Email is required',
  v => v.length >= 5 || 'The e-mail address must contain at least 5 characters',
  v => v.length <= 50 || 'The e-mail address cannot be longer than 50 characters',
  v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Please enter a valid email address',
],
password: '',
confirmPassword: '',
passwordRules: [
  v => !!v || 'Password is required',
  v => v.length >= 8 || 'Password must contain at least 8 characters',
  v => v.length <= 50 || 'Password address cannot be longer than 50 characters',
],
}),

computed: {
 currentTitle () {
  switch (this.step) {
    case 1: return 'Sign-up'
    case 2: return 'Create a password'
    default: return 'Account created'
  }
 },
 },
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed property called "canAdvance" like this

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    step: 1,
    email: '',
    emailRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Email is required',
      v => v.length >= 5 || 'The e-mail address must contain at least 5 characters',
      v => v.length <= 50 || 'The e-mail address cannot be longer than 50 characters',
      v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Please enter a valid email address',
    ],
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    passwordRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Password is required',
      v => v.length >= 8 || 'Password must contain at least 8 characters',
      v => v.length <= 50 || 'Password address cannot be longer than 50 characters',
    ],
  }),

  computed: {
    currentTitle () {
      switch (this.step) {
        case 1: return 'Sign-up'
        case 2: return 'Create a password'
        default: return 'Account created'
      }
    },
      canAdvance() {
           return this.emailRules.every(rule => rule(this.email) === true) && 
              this.passwordRules.every(rule => rule(this.password) === true);
     }
  },
})
```

and then use the property to enable or disable the button.

I would return true or false on each rule instead of the error message, something like this

```
data: {emailRules: [{validator: (v) => {return !!v}, errorMessage: 'Email is required'}]}
```

so you can separate the validation from the error message and adapt your code to show the corresponding message foreach rule